# Ax 2012 AIF adapters

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ax, aif

I would like to understand benefits and disadvantages by using FileAdapter(async mode) and NetTcp(sync mode) for integration with external system (BizTalk is in middle as well). For each of inbound message a the response message should be sent back. (response message should contain error descriptions if something failed or some "Ok" descriptions is success cases)

Let's assume, about hundred different kind of integrations (mostly of them inserts data in AX) are used. Thousends of messages per day for each of integration.

What would be the best approach in this case (from performance, usability point of view)? To use Async mode by FileAdapter (additional outbound message for response) or use NetTcp sync mode( by calling as service)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If having synchronous message exchanges is not a must then I would opt for using the file system adapters, which  can decrease the load on the system, thus improving performance.